# discord.py - How to add a cooldown for every time a user tries to farm XP? (leveling system, on message event) [solved]

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a leveling bot. I found a major issue with gaining XP, and it can be abused **extremely** easily. I want it to have a cooldown after a user sends a message, so when a user spams in a channel to farm XP, they have a .5-second cooldown for each message, to prevent spam. If you spam a lot of messages, you can easily get to the #1 spot, and I don't want that to happen. Everything works with it, the XP gaining, leaderboard, and the level-up message. I've looked on the internet for an answer to this, and none of them helped. Does anyone know? Please and thank you!!! :)

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)

        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when writing the file
        with open('level.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send(':fire: {} has leveled up to **Level {}!**'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end
      embed=discord.Embed(title=':fire: {} has leveled up to **Level {}!**'.format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=0x38ff6a)
      await bot.get_channel(log_channel_id).send(embed=embed)

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
      with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar.url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

JSON file example:

```
{
  "757383943116030074": {
    "123456789012345678": {
      "experience": 0,
      "level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this question, someone posted an answer and it was correct, but they deleted their answer for some reason... Heres the code for anyone else coming here:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                return

        with open('level.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)


        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('level.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

It checks if a user has already sent a message and waits until its time to add XP, and if a user sends a message within that timeframe, it cancels XP.